# spatial index is not included in possible keys

Tags: mysql, indexing, spatial-index

hi I am using `MYSQL 8.0.32`

and I have `club` table and there is `club_point` column which is `point` type.

I have 500,000 records in the table.

and as the picture below, I made a spatial index that only contains club_point.

[image]

but when I execute

```
explain
select * from club  WHERE ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE(ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POINT(37.76452 126.876325)',4326), club_point) <= 100000
```

[image]

It doesn't have any possible keys as well as key.

I found that it could be a SRID problem, but I think It is not.

[image]

any keyword would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Index cannot be used while calculating the distance. Convert your destination point to a circle/rectangle/polygon and test does it contains the club point using a function such as MBRContains() or MBRWithin(). If you need the distance then you may calculate it in outer query but for selected club points only.

Comment: @Akina thank you so much!! By changing query to use ST_Buffer() and ST_contains(), it worked as I expected.

Comment: I think you will have to use a "bounding box"  as discussed in https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/find_nearest_in_mysql#spatial and https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/find_nearest_in_mysql#bounding_box